# Power Automate : How to use variable in items() function

Tags: variables, power-automate, items

I would like to put the name of the list column in a variable and use it in the items() function but didn't get the correct content.

Who can help me ?

What I dit :

- Set variable "Column_Name" (string) to "T_x002d_CCE_x002d_E" - This is the correct name from the column
- Get items from a list
- Apply to each with 'Value' as input
- Set variable "Column_Value" (bolean, same type as column T_x002d_CCE_x002d_E) to items('Apply to each')?['T_x002d_CCE_x002d_E'] **and I get the correct value in Column_Value**

But if I replace the last action by

- Set variable "Column_Value" (bolean, same type as column T_x002d_CCE_x002d_E) to items('Apply to each')?[variables('Column_Name')] **and I don't get the correct value**

  [Picture of compose of variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufBCw.png)
  [Picture of compose with hardcoded column name T_x....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBlfE.png)
  [Picture of compose with items() using variable and output is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWYmK.png)

Comment: That should work. Add a Compose action after your last step and add this expression: `variables('Column_Name')` just to validate that the variable is indeed correct.

Comment: Thank for answer but didn't work .
How can I add print screen to this question ?

Comment: I add Print screens - One with compose of the variable, one with compose when I use items(..)?['T_x002d_CCE_x002d_E'] and the last one with compose when I use items('Apply to each')?[variables('Column_Name')]

Comment: Could you add a print screen of the last compose (this one with items() using variables)  in edit mode please. Maybe also try `items('Apply_to_each')?[string(variables('Column_Name'))]`

Comment: This is the content of the last compose using variable 
items('Apply_to_each')?[string(variables('Column_Name'))] and also part of  the content of items('Apply_to_each')

{
  ....
  "Title": "CFG - APF_BB_Process ",
  "Item_Name": "Configuration Management",
  "Applicability_Reason#Id": 5,
  "T_x002d_Analytics": false,
  "T_x002d_CEE_x002d_E": false,
  "T_x002d_CEE_x002d_I": false,
  .....
}

Comment: Urm.... Just to confirm is it `T_x002d_CEE_x002d_E` or `T_x002d_CCE_x002d_E` :) :) Your first snip shows `CCE` which is incorrect.

Comment: Many thanks to detect this. It was so obvious. Issue solved. Many thanks.